# my Curl command display special characters in the output

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I am running the following command in CLI:

[image]

it displays correct output on the scree like average Speed Time etc. But the D:\wajid.txt contains only special characters, not the output that is shown in the CLI. The screenshot of Wajid.txt if given below:

[image]

How can I save the actual output shown on the CLI scree in the text file?

Comment: [Don't post text as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You are confused about the ouput from `curl`, and about encodings. Don't use Notepad to view the output; or, at a minimum, understand what encoding it's in (if indeed it is actually text).

Comment: To render the progress bar, curl needs to render a bunch of control characters (in particular to move the cursor). That may be what you are seeing in stdout.

Comment: Er um, no, the status messages are all on stderr.

Comment: @tripleee: fair enough. I assume the output file would be sent to the file specified with `-o, --output`, so what goes to stdout?

Comment: The default without `-o` is to print the download to standard output. There are various options to print other things to stdout (remote host, timing information, download size, etc). In their absence, nothing else gets printed to stdout; diagnostics always go to stderr, as with any well-behaved utility.

Comment: I use this command and it run successfully, 
curl -o- http://localhost:8080/wm/core/controllers/switches/json >wajid.txt
to enable statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this command and it run successfully to enable statistics in floodlight controller:

```
curl -o- localhost:8080/wm/core/controllers/switches/json >wajid.txt
```